# Trying to open a feature file in Eclipse and getting Editor could not be initialized

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

Am unable to open any cucumber file. I tried uninstalling, reinstalling cucumber jar, clean up project... check for version compatibility... nothing worked. I looked through the already asked questions and answers, but could not find any suitable answer for my issue, hence posting the question. Here is the detailed error:

> Editor could not be initialized. java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.findIndexMatches(MatchLocator.java:275)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.search(PatternSearchJob.java:109)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.execute(PatternSearchJob.java:65)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:277)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:516)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:584)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.steps.jdt.StepDefinitions.getAllAnnotationsInPackage(StepDefinitions.java:327)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.steps.jdt.StepDefinitions.getCukeSteps(StepDefinitions.java:135)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.jdt.JDTStepDefinitions.collectCukeStepsFromSource(JDTStepDefinitions.java:116)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.jdt.JDTStepDefinitions.getSteps(JDTStepDefinitions.java:79)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.reloadSteps(ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.java:43)
>     at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.(ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.java:26)
>     at cucumber.eclipse.editor.editors.Editor.doSetInput(Editor.java:177)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2177)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:572)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:536)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3252)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

Comment: Please, reformat your question for more readability, put your exception details in a "Blockquote". There is a button on top of question editor.

Comment: Try this out -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529209

Comment: @Grasshopper, i tried, but did not work

Comment: @Pavel, the formatting looked fine when i pasted details in the comment window but became like this as soon as i posted

Comment: hi all, i uninstalled cucumber plugin and installed natural... now am able to open the feature file. I request some more help on this issue.